# Restrict GitHub organization forking

Tags: github

After setting up an organization, members of my organization have the ability to fork repositories into my organization. Is there a way to prevent this?

If the settings are correct they should see the following:

> You don't have permission to fork on these organizations.

Answer (score 3):

In order to prevent members of an organization from forking a repository "into the organization", you can take away their ability to "create" repositories.

By going to the "Settings" of the organization, then to "Member privileges", under "Repository Creation" the box next to "Private" will likely be checked, which makes the box next to "Public" automatically checked. By un-checking "Private", you will then be able to un-check "Public", and now non-admin members will no longer be able to fork repositories "inot the organization".

I have added a screenshot below, which summarizes the above paragraph:

[image]

Now when someone tried to fork a repository "into the organization", it is likely to say "insufficient permission", as shown in the red box below:

[image]

The one disadvantage of the above approach, is that "ordinary" members can no longer create repositories "in the organization", but I think that creating repositories within the organization can be exclusively reserved for administrators anyway. In my organization, I had a repository called "HPQC", then multiple erroneously created forks called "HPQC-1", "HPQC-2", etc., because users didn't quite know how forking works (i.e. to create their own fork, rather than making a fork that clutters the organization's front GitHub page).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. There are two types of membership to an organization, Owner and Member. Members have the ability to create new repositories, including forks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to prevent [forking of repositories of an organization](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-the-forking-policy-for-your-organization) by unchecking the box under `Profile > Your Organizations > Settings > Member privileges > Repository Forking`, as shown in the figure.

[image: forbid forking]

Comment: Interesting, though my option shows up as only "Allow forking of private repositories. If enabled, forking is allowed on private and public repositories. If disabled, forking is only allowed on public repositories. This setting is also configurable per-repository."

Comment: Forbidding forking is only possible on internal and private repositories of an organisation. Public repositories can always be forked.

Answer (score 0):

If you use GHE (GitHub Enterprise), you now also have:

> ### [Enterprise fork policies for organizations](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-27-enterprise-fork-policies-for-organizations) (Sep. 2022)
>
> Previously, [we announced](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-27-improved-innersource-collaboration-and-enterprise-fork-policies/) the ability for enterprise owners to limit where private and internal repository forks can be created.
> We heard from some customers that they need a more granular control over fork permissions for each organization within the enterprise.
>
> Now, we've added the ability for enterprise organization admins to set fork policy at the organization level, further restricting enterprise policy.
> Forking can be limited to organizations within the enterprise, within the same organization, user accounts and organization within the enterprise, user accounts, or everywhere.
>
> Fork policies cascade from the enterprise policy to organization policy to repository policy.
> Enterprise policies dictate the policy options available for organizations, i.e.
> an organization admin can only set a **more restrictive** forking policy than the enterprise allows.
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/90000203/191866329-85401400-15d6-4a1b-ae4a-fe8a379f0524.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of organization fork policy settings]